# Java Gui Sum of Two Number

Tags: java, user-interface

I made a GUI which basically adds the numbers from the two textfield. The problem is, if I leave the other textfield blank and the other textfield has a number, the result textfield is not updating.

```
public class AdditionGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private TextField tf1 , tf2 , tf3;
    private Label sign, equalsign;
    private int sum = 0;

    AdditionGui(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tf1 = new TextField(5);
        add(tf1);
        tf1.addActionListener(this);
        sign = new Label("+");
        add(sign);
        tf2 = new TextField(5);
        add(tf2);
        tf2.addActionListener(this);

        equalsign = new Label("=");
        add(equalsign);
        tf3 = new TextField(5);
        add(tf3);

        setTitle("Sum of two numbers");
        setSize(220,120);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        sum = val1 + val2;
        tf3.setText("" + sum);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A blank text field means its contents cannot be parsed to an `Integer`. In that case this line of your code will throw [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) (if `tf1` is blank).

```java
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
```

In your `actionPerformed()` method, check that `getText()` returns a number.
I suggest setting a blank text field to zero, for example:

```java
String text1 = tf1.getText();
if (text1.length() == 0) {
   text1 = "0";
}
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
String text2 = tf2.getText();
if (text2.length() == 0) {
   text2 = "0";
}
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);
int sum = val1 + val2;
tf3.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Now something for you to think about.
What happens if the user enters a non-digit into one of the text fields?